# JavaFX show tooltip in a fixed position relative to the node

Tags: java, javafx

**Goal:** To make ToolTip always show in the bottom-right position of the node

**Problem:** Regardless my efforts, I'm unable to override or adapt ToolTip behavior. It always shows up based on the mouse position.

**MRE:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label = new Label("TEST\nTEST\nTEST");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("TOOLTIP");
        tooltip.setShowDelay(Duration.seconds(0.5));
        label.setTooltip(tooltip);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(label));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        
        stage.show();

        Point2D p = label.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
        label.getTooltip().show(label,
                p.getX() + label.getScene().getX() + label.getScene().getWindow().getX(),
                p.getY() + label.getScene().getY() + label.getScene().getWindow().getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

To make it clearer, this is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Instead, ToolTip always shows on top of the node:

[image]

Comment: You can use a [Popup with an anchor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Popup.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 for what @jewelsea suggested.

You can create a custom Tooltip to set this functionality across multiple nodes.
The idea is to set the anchor every time just before showing the Tooltip so that it can work well even when the window is moved across the screen.

You can check the idea in the below demo:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TooltipAnchoringDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label1 = new Label("TEST1\nTEST1\nTEST1");
        label1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        Label label2 = new Label("TEST2\nTEST2\nTEST2");
        label2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        Label label3 = new Label("TEST3\nTEST3\nTEST3");
        label3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

        CustomTooltip tooltip = CustomTooltip.install("TOOLTIP 1", label1);
        tooltip.setShowDelay(Duration.seconds(0.5));

        CustomTooltip.install("TOOLTIP 2", label2);
        CustomTooltip.install("TOOLTIP 3", label3);

        HBox root = new HBox(15, label1, label2, label3);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 180);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Tooltip Demo");

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

class CustomTooltip extends Tooltip {
    /**
     * Pixel offset from the node in the y-axis to display the tooltip.
     * You can keep it to 0. Normally I don't want to keep it very near to the node.
     */
    private static final int Y_OFFSET = 2;

    private Node node;

    public CustomTooltip(final String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public static CustomTooltip install(String msg, Node node) {
        CustomTooltip tooltip = new CustomTooltip(msg);
        tooltip.node = node;
        install(node, tooltip);
        return tooltip;
    }

    @Override
    protected void show() {
        /* Set the new position before showing. */
        Point2D anchor = anchor(node);
        setAnchorX(anchor.getX());
        setAnchorY(anchor.getY());
        
        super.show();
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the anchor point for the tooltip.
     *
     * @param n the node
     * @return the anchor position
     */
    private Point2D anchor(final Node n) {
        /* Get the node bounds on the screen. */
        final Bounds bounds = n.localToScreen(n.getBoundsInLocal());

        /* Calculate the opening position based on node bounds . */
        final Point2D openPosition = new Point2D(bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMaxY() + Y_OFFSET);

        return openPosition;
    }
}
```